# multiple conditionals effciently

Tags: python, loops, combinatorics

How can I execute the following code in a more efficient way in python? The input flags are binary valued. The output depends on all possible permutations of the flag.

```
def f1():

    return 1

def f2():

    return 2

def f3():

    return 3    


def g(p1, p2, p3):

    if p1 ==  1 & p2 == 0 & p3 == 0:
        f1()

    elif: p1 == 0 & p2 == 1 & p3 == 0:
        f2()

    elif: p1 == 0 & p2 == 0 & p3 == 1:
        f3()

    elif: p1 == 1 & p2 == 1 & p3 == 1:
        f1()
        f2()
```

and so on.

Comment: If `p1 == 1 & p2 == 1 & p3 == 1` you don't wanna run `f3()`?

Comment: *and so on*? It doesn't seem like the desired behavior is obvious from what you are showing here.

Comment: Yes I do. Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: What about if `p1` and `p2` are 1, but `p3` is 0?

Comment: Then run f1 and f2 but not f3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the arguments `(p1, p2, p3)` as flags, you could always pack those arguments as a list using `*args` (see [this](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs) and [this](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/)) and put your functions in a list (yep, Python lets you do that) and get something like:

```
def f1():
    return 1

def f2():
    return 2

def f3():
    return 3 

def g(*ps):
    functions = [f1, f2, f3]
    for i, p in enumerate(ps):
        if p == 1:  # Could do just `if p:` (0 evaluates to False, anything else to True)
            print(functions[i])()  # Notice the () to actually call the function 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Run 1 0 0")
    g(1, 0, 0)
    print("Run 1 1 0")
    g(1, 1, 0)
    print("Run 0 1 0")
    g(0, 1, 0)
    print("Run 1 1 1")
    g(1, 1, 1)
```

As per [ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393290/multiple-conditionals-effciently/40393400#comment68038376_40393400) to this answer, you could even shorten the code a bit more. For instance, using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
def g(*ps):
    functions = [f1, f2, f3]
    for function, p in zip(functions, ps):
        if p:
            print(function())
```

Or using [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) (you'll need to `import itertools` at the top of your file):

```
def g(*ps):
    functions = [f1, f2, f3]
    for function in itertools.compress(functions, ps):
        print(function())
```

Comment: Why use `enumerate` when you could just do `for func, p in zip(functions, ps):` and avoid indexing? For that matter, you could simplify even further with `itertools`: `for func in itertools.compress(functions, ps): func()`, avoiding any tests at all (`compress` will return the function corresponding to each truthy `p`).

Comment: Very true! As a matter of fact, I didn't even know the `itertools.compress`!!  (TIL) **:-)** I did think about the zip... I was trying to deviate as little as I could from the initial code? But you're right: the OP asked for a more efficient way, and those are.

Comment: I'm gonna go find one of your answers and upvote it!! **:-D**

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the three bits into a single number and then test the value of that number like this:

```
def g(p1, p2, p3):

   v = (p1 << 2) + (p2 << 1) + p3

    if v == 4: # 100
        f1()
    elif v == 2: # 010
        f2()
    elif v == 1: # 001
        f3()
    elif v == 7: # 111
        f1()
        f2()
```

Comment: I'd personally use `0b100`/`0b010`/etc. as the constant to make it slightly more obvious, but yeah, I just posted (and then deleted) this exact answer 15 seconds after you.